# How to get the transactions on BscScan by an address?

Tags: api, bscscan

I am trying to get all the transactions by an address, because I want to get a specific transaction by the method (that occurs at a date time when a contract is created) and the an address. I know there is an API, but I can't find it.

For example, on this address https://bscscan.com/address/0xbe807dddb074639cd9fa61b47676c064fc50d62c I can see the methods of that address so I could go to the specific contract, but I can't get it by an API. Is it possible?

Would it be better to use a scraping?

Answer (score 0):

You need use this free version - good way
https://bscscan.com/apis , then you can iterate every transaction.

Or do loop on all blocks and iterate every block - bad way.